# Wild card URL rewrite of subdomain to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am in a situation where an user can create his blog in a subdomain.

Users will create blogs and enter the address he wants like say,

`abcd.domain.com` Then my php code creates a directory called `abcd`.

To view the blog user will type in `abcd.domain.com` in his browser and I want a `.htaccess` code which will rewrite the url and open the files inside the `domain.com/abcd` 
But for the user the url in the browser should stay `abcd.domain.com`

Currently I am trying this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But this gives me 404 even though I have a file `test.html` inside the test folder and trying to view that page.

Also in this situation I will have to manually make change to the .htaccess file for URL rewrite. What I want to know is if it is possible to have a wild card subdomain redirect to the respective directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L,QSA]
```

`REQUEST_URI` with leading `/`.

With wild card subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: While the first part of your code solved the 404 for the test folder, the 2nd part for wild card doesn't works. When I try to reload the same url that works with the first code using the 2nd .htaccess code I get error msg

Comment: `Not Found
The requested URL /test/test/redirect:/test/test/test.html/redirect:/test/test/test.html/redirect:/test/test/test.html/redirect:/test/test/test.html/test.html/test.html/redirect:/test/test/test.html/test.html/test.html/redirect:/test/test/test.html/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: You only use the 2nd part ? (and delete the test part)

Comment: Yes I am only using the 2nd part and deleted the first part.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it takes more than a rewrite rule to have wildcard subdomains. Just fyi.

You need to have created a `wildcard DNS record` for subdomains and also tell apache to use any subdomain request by having a `ServerAlias` of `*.domain.com` in the apache config.

Then try your rule this way and see if it works for you.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ok... did you try the rule?

Comment: I was in a hurry to get it live for a demo purpose to my client so didn't have the time to debug and check the error logs. For now I have done a very insecure patch, I am using php script to append the .htaccess with the rule for each dir whenever a new subdomain is created